# Google App Engine is sending SVG with wrong mime-type

Tags: google-app-engine, svg, mime-types

I'm using Google App Engine with Python 2.7 and I'm trying to use an svg-file as a sprite-sheet.

For some reason this works fine on Win7 and Ubuntu, but not on Vista or Mac (Using the latest Chrome and Firefox in each case).

Here it's sent with mime-type "application/octet-stream" and the browsers prompts to download it, instead of displaying it.

I tried overriding the mime-type in my app.yaml like this:

```
- url: /img/.*\.svg
  static_dir: public/img
  mime_type: image/svg+xml

- url: /img
  static_dir: public/img
```

But that didn't change anything.

I also tried to route requests for svg-files through their own url like this

```
- url: /img/svg
  static_dir: public/img
  mime_type: image/svg+xml

- url: /img
  static_dir: public/img
```

But that results in the file being sent with mime-type "img/png", so the browser will at least *try* to display it, but can't.

Just to make sure, I tried each combination as stated and also with the headers-options:

```
- url: /img/svg
  static_dir: public/img
  http_headers:
    mime-type: image/svg+xml
```

Without success.

Any help please?

[edit]

After some more testing, it seems like on Ubuntu using the local app-launcher, it sends the svg as `text/html` and when deployed it uses `application/octet-stream`, regardless of what I put in the app.yaml.

Does anybody have experience with this? The only way I can solve this is to insert the svg-code into the page directly, which kinda sucks. It's a graphic and I want to treat it that way.

[more edit]

In the end, I put this in the yaml-file and it seems to work:

```
- url: /img/.*\.svg
  static_dir: public/img
  http_headers:
    content_type: image/svg+xml

- url: /img
  static_dir: public/img
```

Comment: Please post an edit to your OP with the full .yaml code including the answer?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try:

```
http_headers:
  content-type: image/svg+xml
```

Comment: Thanks, that seems to work fine! Any idea why it behaves so differently on the different client computers?

Comment: Serving responses with an incorrect MIME type is always going to have unpredictable results. Some clients will try to guess; they all have different rules for how that guess works, and some may rely on operating system support to do the guessing and/or display. It's more aggravating that AppEngine can't guess the right MIME type; that seems pretty simple in this case.

Comment: Why does the `mime_type` flag in the `.yaml` file not work? It's in their documentation: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/appconfig#Python_app_yaml_Static_file_handlers  Seems like a GAE bug.