# SVG file does not load properly on app engine

Tags: angular, google-app-engine

I have an angular application deployed in app engine. I have some image resources to load on certain page of the app. When I serve it locally using `live-server` it works perfectly fine.

> live-server --port=8080 --entry-file=./index.html

However, when I deploy in app engine, one of my svg files doest load on the page though when I try to inspect element it's there but the color is invisible.

Here is my (app.yaml) file:

```
runtime: python27
threadsafe: true
api_version: 1

handlers:
- url: /(.*\.(gif|png|jpeg|jpg|css|js|ico|svg))$
  static_files: knowledge-space/\1
  upload: knowledge-space/(.*)

- url: /(.*)
  static_files: knowledge-space/index.html
  upload: knowledge-space/index.html
```

Here is the svg file (star-rating.icons.svg):

```
    <symbol id="star-empty" viewBox="0 0 34 32">
        <path class="path-star-empty"
              d="M33.412 12.395l-11.842-1.021-4.628-10.904-4.628 10.92-11.842 1.005 8.993 7.791-2.701 11.579 10.179-6.144 10.179 6.144-2.685-11.579 8.976-7.791zM16.941 22.541l-6.193 3.739 1.647-7.049-5.468-4.744 7.214-0.626 2.8-6.638 2.816 6.654 7.214 0.626-5.468 4.744 1.647 7.049-6.209-3.755z"/>
    </symbol>

    <symbol id="star-half" viewBox="0 0 34 32">
        <path class="path-star-half"
              d="M 33.412,12.395 21.57,11.374 16.942,0.47 12.314,11.39 0.472,12.395 9.465,20.186 6.764,31.765 16.943,25.621 27.122,31.765 24.437,20.186 33.413,12.395 Z M 16.941,22.541 c 0,0 -0.297971,-14.6455833 0,-15.318 l 2.816,6.654 7.214,0.626 -5.468,4.744 1.647,7.049 z"/>
        </symbol>

    <symbol id="star-filled" viewBox="0 0 34 32">
        <path class="path-star-filled"
              d="M16.941 25.621l10.179 6.144-2.701-11.579 8.993-7.791-11.842-1.005-4.628-10.92-4.628 10.92-11.842 1.005 8.993 7.791-2.701 11.579z"/>
    </symbol>

</defs>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some possible solutions for this to be happening. Most of the cases, it's related to the configuration in the `app.yaml` file - for example, it might be related to the Mime Type being read on the `app.yaml` file. Considering that, I would recommend you to take a look at the following posts from the Community, where there are similar cases to yours, on how to load images (SVG) in web pages.

- [How to configure Google AppEngine to work with vector graphic?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45100138/how-to-configure-google-appengine-to-work-with-vector-graphic)
- [Google App Engine is sending SVG with wrong mime-type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24106691/google-app-engine-is-sending-svg-with-wrong-mime-type)

In addition to that, there is other post from the Community - [Images not displaying html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25941120/images-not-displaying-html-img)  - that might help you, providing a solution using the tag `<img>`, that I would recommend you to look as well.

I found this article that shows how to use SVG from scratch, in case you want to take a look as well: [Using Google's App Engine to serve SVG files](http://ryanarn.blogspot.com/2011/04/using-googles-app-engine-to-serve-svg.html)

Let me know if the information helped you!

Comment: This solves my problem. I added http headers specifically for svg file type only. Thank you so much
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24106691/google-app-engine-is-sending-svg-with-wrong-mime-type

Comment: Hi @str028 that's great! Please, consider accepting my answer, since it solved your problem! :)